# Регулярные выражения XML notepad++ Как удалить блок offer, если внутри есть определенное значение (available="false")?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, xml, notepad++

Нужно удалить все блоки (всё что между тегами <offer  включая сами теги, при условии что между этими тегами есть значение available="false"
Для того, чтобы удалить все карточки товаров из файла которых нет в наличии.

```
<offer id="6136DS" available="true">
<name>Название товара</name>
<description>Описание товара </description>
<currencyId>EUR</currencyId>
<categoryId>6039</categoryId>
<picture>Ссылка на картинку</picture>
<price>7.9</price>
<quantity_in_stock>8</quantity_in_stock>
<vendor>Бренд</vendor>
<vendorCode>503690</vendorCode>
<param name="Каталог">2022</param>
<param name="Цвет"/>
<param name="Материал">материал</param>
<param name="Размер"/>
</offer>

<offer id="6138DS" available="false">
<name>Название товара</name>
<description>Описание товара</description>
<currencyId>EUR</currencyId>
<categoryId>6039</categoryId>
<picture>Ссылка на картинку</picture>
<price>5.9</price>
<quantity_in_stock>0</quantity_in_stock>
<vendor>Бренд</vendor>
<vendorCode>503789</vendorCode>
<param name="Каталог"/>
<param name="Цвет"/>
<param name="Материал">Материал</param>
<param name="Размер"/>
</offer>

<offer id="6140DS" available="true">
<name>Название товара</name>
<description>Описание товара </description>
<currencyId>EUR</currencyId>
<categoryId>6039</categoryId>
<picture>Ссылка на картинку</picture>
<price>7.5</price>
<quantity_in_stock>11</quantity_in_stock>
<vendor>Бренд</vendor>
<vendorCode>503800</vendorCode>
<param name="Каталог">2022</param>
<param name="Цвет"/>
<param name="Материал">Материал</param>
<param name="Размер"/>
</offer>

<offer id="6142DS" available="false">
<name>Название товара</name>
<description>Описание товара </description>
<currencyId>EUR</currencyId>
<categoryId>6039</categoryId>
<picture>Ссылка на картинку</picture>
<price>10.9</price>
<available/>
<quantity_in_stock>0</quantity_in_stock>
<vendor>Бренд</vendor>
<vendorCode>502790</vendorCode>
<param name="Каталог">12/13</param>
<param name="Цвет"/>
<param name="Материал"/>
<param name="Размер"/>
</offer>
```

Comment: Для таких задач лучше использовать XSLT-преобразование. Для этого в Notepad++ есть плагин [XML Tools].

Comment: О, если не сложно верните правильный ответ на первого ответившего, решение с плагином более правильное, мой ответ для примера дан, спасибо!

Comment: Ок, вернул.
Но ваше решение тоже работает. И оно компактней.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот решение на основе XSLT.

Оно использует так называемый *Identity Transform* pattern.

Один единственный шаблон (template) удаляет ненужные offers.

**Начальный XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <offer id="6136DS" available="true">
        <name>Название товара</name>
        <description>Описание товара</description>
        <currencyId>EUR</currencyId>
        <categoryId>6039</categoryId>
        <picture>Ссылка на картинку</picture>
        <price>7.9</price>
        <quantity_in_stock>8</quantity_in_stock>
        <vendor>Бренд</vendor>
        <vendorCode>503690</vendorCode>
        <param name="Каталог">2022</param>
        <param name="Цвет"/>
        <param name="Материал">материал</param>
        <param name="Размер"/>
    </offer>
    <offer id="6138DS" available="false">
        <name>Название товара</name>
        <description>Описание товара</description>
        <currencyId>EUR</currencyId>
        <categoryId>6039</categoryId>
        <picture>Ссылка на картинку</picture>
        <price>5.9</price>
        <quantity_in_stock>0</quantity_in_stock>
        <vendor>Бренд</vendor>
        <vendorCode>503789</vendorCode>
        <param name="Каталог"/>
        <param name="Цвет"/>
        <param name="Материал">Материал</param>
        <param name="Размер"/>
    </offer>
    <offer id="6140DS" available="true">
        <name>Название товара</name>
        <description>Описание товара</description>
        <currencyId>EUR</currencyId>
        <categoryId>6039</categoryId>
        <picture>Ссылка на картинку</picture>
        <price>7.5</price>
        <quantity_in_stock>11</quantity_in_stock>
        <vendor>Бренд</vendor>
        <vendorCode>503800</vendorCode>
        <param name="Каталог">2022</param>
        <param name="Цвет"/>
        <param name="Материал">Материал</param>
        <param name="Размер"/>
    </offer>
    <offer id="6142DS" available="false">
        <name>Название товара</name>
        <description>Описание товара</description>
        <currencyId>EUR</currencyId>
        <categoryId>6039</categoryId>
        <picture>Ссылка на картинку</picture>
        <price>10.9</price>
        <available/>
        <quantity_in_stock>0</quantity_in_stock>
        <vendor>Бренд</vendor>
        <vendorCode>502790</vendorCode>
        <param name="Каталог">12/13</param>
        <param name="Цвет"/>
        <param name="Материал"/>
        <param name="Размер"/>
    </offer>
</root>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="offer[@available='false']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Результат**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<root>
  <offer id="6136DS" available="true">
    <name>Название товара</name>
    <description>Описание товара</description>
    <currencyId>EUR</currencyId>
    <categoryId>6039</categoryId>
    <picture>Ссылка на картинку</picture>
    <price>7.9</price>
    <quantity_in_stock>8</quantity_in_stock>
    <vendor>Бренд</vendor>
    <vendorCode>503690</vendorCode>
    <param name="Каталог">2022</param>
    <param name="Цвет"/>
    <param name="Материал">материал</param>
    <param name="Размер"/>
  </offer>
  <offer id="6140DS" available="true">
    <name>Название товара</name>
    <description>Описание товара</description>
    <currencyId>EUR</currencyId>
    <categoryId>6039</categoryId>
    <picture>Ссылка на картинку</picture>
    <price>7.5</price>
    <quantity_in_stock>11</quantity_in_stock>
    <vendor>Бренд</vendor>
    <vendorCode>503800</vendorCode>
    <param name="Каталог">2022</param>
    <param name="Цвет"/>
    <param name="Материал">Материал</param>
    <param name="Размер"/>
  </offer>
</root>
```